# firebase authenticate as google account admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase hosting (with functions + database) to provide some status information to my audience (There is no need for login or user accounts). Currently as an admin I am logging into firebase console with my google login and updating the database manually with status updates.

I want to create an administrative login page that can authenticate if (and only) its the firebase admin google login and then allow writing to database from a client-side UI page. Is this possible?